# How To Keep Feeder Mice if I Keep Kosher?

Tags: feeding, snakes, mice

I'm researching and adding up prices for getting a pet snake, but I have one major issue:
I keep kosher, and if I put frozen feeder mice in the freezer, that would be unkosher.

I've tried looking for mini-freezers online, but I only find mini-fridges with tiny freezers, and they're even then, they're out of my price range.

How should I store frozen mice if I can't keep them in the house (they can be stored in the garage)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. It sounds like you can buy a small freezer and keep it in the garage. If you're looking for recommendations on what freezer to buy, [shopping questions are out of scope here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/should-we-allow-shopping-or-product-species-recommendation-questions) and this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Buy a separate freezer, it doesn't matter where you put the freezer - as to affording it etc, that's off topic.